# I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR on google sheet "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined searchRecord @ Code.gs:213"

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, forms, google-apps-script

**Keeps bringing up an error at the point  i try to iterate with for loop**, i've crossed checked but still can't find something wrong. dont know what to do to get the result.

var rowValue = values[0]; this is actually where it keeps giving me errors.

```
function searchRecord() {
  
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("User Form"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database"); ////delcare a variable and set with the Database worksheet
    
  var str       = shUserForm.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var values    = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //getting the entire values from the used range and assigning it to values variable
  var valuesFound=false; //variable to store boolean value
  
  for (var i = 0; i = values.length; i++) 
    {
    var rowValue = values[0]; //declaraing a variable and storing the value
   
    //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
    if (rowValue[0] == str){     
      shUserForm.getRange("C7").setValue(rowValue[0]) ;
      shUserForm.getRange("C9").setValue(rowValue[1]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C11").setValue(rowValue[2]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C13").setValue(rowValue[3]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C15").setValue(rowValue[4]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C17").setValue(rowValue[5]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C19").setValue(rowValue[6]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C21").setValue(rowValue[7]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C23").setValue(rowValue[8]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C25").setValue(rowValue[9]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C27").setValue(rowValue[10]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C29").setValue(rowValue[11]);
      shUserForm.getRange("C31").setValue(rowValue[12]);
      
      return; //come out from the search function
      
      }
  }

if(valuesFound==false){
  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("No record found!");
 }

}
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i = values.length; i++)` you mean `for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)` - and `rowValue = values[i]` otherwise the code makes no sense and could run forever - also `return; //come out from the search function` means `if(valuesFound==false){` will never run, and `valuesFound` is never anything but false

Comment: however ... the the error suggests that `values` is undefined ... so how does `i = values.length` not throw an error ... are you sure the code in the question is actual code?

Comment: thanks a lot, guess i missed that. appreciated.

Comment: guess it kept ignoring anything lesser than values.lenth.

Comment: but if `values` is undefined, trying to access `values.length` will **throw** an error, so you should never have gotten the error you claim

Comment: @JaromandaX It's possible to get the length but not the first item because `.getValues()`  [returns two-dimensional array of values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and he doesn't specify where the TypeError throws (values[0] or rowValue[0]) in the exception message. Regarding to the main question, can you please share a spreadsheet as example or an image so we can better understand which type of data you are working with?

Comment: a two dimensional array you say @JoseVasquez ... so ... values would be something like `[[1,2],[2,3]]` ... which ***still isn't undefined*** ... if values is undefined when you access `values[0]` ... it's ***values*** that's undefined ... so `values.length` will still trhow the same error as `values[0]` ... yet ... it seems it does not

Comment: Is this the entire code you are using? Can you please clarify _where_ exactly are you getting the error? Is the 213th line the one you share? Can you share a screenshot of it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that data is actually in the sheet, because if it is empty, it will throw an error.

Try and check to see what the array you are working with actually looks like using [Logger.log](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object))(array or value).

Are you expecting one row to match or multiple? If only one, then you should `break` [out of the loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp) after you have found your match, otherwise the script runs until all rows have been tested, even if the first one was the match.

When describing an error it is helpful to state the error, as opposed to saying "There is an error".

Comment: sure, but why would values be undefined here `var rowValue = values[0]` ... but not here `i = values.length` :p

Comment: Perhaps that particular index is undefined, like so: [,"two", "three"]

Comment: Then the name of the database / sheet may be invalid.

Comment: but why is values.length OK, but when trying to access values[0], values in undefined ... see the impossibility of the question?

Comment: See above comment, `values[0]` can be undefined if any other index is not undefined, for example `values[1]` may contain a value. In that case `values.length` is 2, but only values[1] has a value.

Comment: sure, yeah I understand, values[0] could be undefined, .... here's the ELI5 version of what I see is impossible: look at the question ... `var rowValue = values[0];` results in  *cannot read property 0 of undefined* ... so, in that line, what would be undefined to cause that error .... is it `var`? is it `rowValue`, is it `values[0]` .... or, *drumroll* ... is it `values` so, yeah, stop repeating that it's perfectly OK for `values[0]` to be undefined - because, yes, it is - but that's irrelevant to the issue as described in the question